# QuickBooks Desktop PHP Dev Kit Customer Authenticate/Add

Tags: php, quickbooks

My QuickBooks XML version is 13.0. I've used example_web_connector_auth.php(https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/docs/web_connector/example_web_connector_auth.php). It should have added a customer. But nothing is added. I don't know what is wrong with it or how I can fix it? The core error is seemingly-"Response is not well-formed XML". It may be a SOAP Exception though I'm not sure yet.

The PHP error log is like below. It contains no error involving XML, just returning SQL deprecation message:

```
[02-Nov-2015 14:55:28 America/New_York] PHP Deprecated:  mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in C:\xampp\htdocs\qb\QuickBooks\Driver\Sql\Mysql.php on line 289
```

The modified SQL Log is:

```
   (12, NULL, 0, 'Handler is starting up...: array (\n  ''qb_company_file''  => NULL,\n  ''qbwc_min_version'' => NULL,\n  ''qbwc_wait_before_next_update'' => NULL,\n  ''qbwc_min_run_every_n_seconds'' => NULL,\n  ''qbwc_version_warning_message'' => NULL,\n  ''qbwc_version_error_message'' => NULL,\n  ''qbwc_interactive_url'' => NULL,\n  ''autoadd_missing_requestid'' => true,\n  ''check_valid_requestid'' => true,\n  ''server_version'' => ''PHP QuickBooks SOAP Server v3.0 at /qb/docs/web_connector/example_web_connector_auth.php'',\n  ''authenticate'' => ''_quickbooks_custom_auth'',\n  ''authenticate_dsn'' => NULL,\n  ''map_application_identifiers'' => true,\n  ''allow_remote_addr'' => \n  array (\n  ),\n  ''deny_remote_addr'' => \n  array (\n  ),\n  ''convert_unix_newlines'' => true,\n  ''deny_concurrent_logins'' => false,\n  ''deny_concurrent_timeout'' => 60,\n  ''deny_reallyfast_logins'' => true,\n  ''deny_reallyfast_timeout'' => 600,\n  ''masking'' => true,\n)', '2015-11-02 14:36:01'),
   (13, NULL, 0, 'Incoming HTTP Headers: User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 4.0.30319.42000)\nContent-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8\nSOAPAction: "http://developer.intuit.com/authenticate"\nHost: localhost:24260\nContent-Length: 384\nExpect: 100-continue\n', '2015-11-02 14:36:01'),
   (14, NULL, 0, 'Incoming SOAP Request: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><authenticate xmlns="http://developer.intuit.com/"><strUserName>quickbooks</strUserName><strPassword>xxxxxxxx</strPassword></authenticate></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>', '2015-11-02 14:36:01'),
   (15, NULL, 0, 'authenticate()', '2015-11-02 14:36:01'),
   (16, NULL, 0, 'Calling auth callback [function]: _quickbooks_custom_auth', '2015-11-02 14:36:01'),
   (17, NULL, 0, 'Calling auth function: _quickbooks_custom_auth', '2015-11-02 14:36:01'),
   (18, 1, 0, 'Login via _quickbooks_custom_auth: quickbooks', '2015-11-02 14:36:02'),
   (19, NULL, 0, 'Outgoing SOAP Response: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n          <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" \n             xmlns:ns1="http://developer.intuit.com/">\n                <SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:authenticateResponse><ns1:authenticateResult><ns1:string>b221c6f1-17b1-6164-9578-3b6760753d5c</ns1:string>\n<ns1:string>C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\Intuit\\QuickBooks\\Sample Company Files\\QuickBooks Enterprise Solutions 14.0\\sample_product-based business.QBW</ns1:string>\n</ns1:authenticateResult></ns1:authenticateResponse>\n            </SOAP-ENV:Body>\n          </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>', '2015-11-02 14:36:02');
```

And the QWClog.txt returns the lines below:

```
20151102.19:55:25 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_serverVersion() : *** Calling serverVersion().
20151102.19:55:26 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_serverVersion() : Actual error received from web service for serverVersion call: <Response is not well-formed XML.>. For backward compatibility of all webservers, QBWC will catch all errors under app-not-supporting-serverVersion.
20151102.19:55:27 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_serverVersion() : This application does not contain support for serverVersion. Allowing update operation for backward compatibility.
20151102.19:55:27 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_clientVersion() : *** Calling clientVersion() with following parameter:<productVersion="2.1.0.30">
20151102.19:55:27 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.updateWS() : Actual error received from web service for clientVersion call: <Response is not well-formed XML.>. For backward compatibility of all webservers, QBWC will catch all errors under app-not-supporting-clientVersion.
20151102.19:55:27 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_clientVersion() : This application does not contain support for clientVersion. Allowing update operation for backward compatibility.
20151102.19:55:27 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : Authenticating to application 'QuickBooks Integrator', username = 'quickbooks'
20151102.19:55:28 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : *** Calling authenticate() with following parameters:<userName="quickbooks"><password=<MaskedForSecurity>
20151102.19:55:29 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : QBWC1012: Authentication failed due to following error message.
Response is not well-formed XML.
More info:
StackTrace =    at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
at QBWebConnector.localhost.WCWebServiceDoc.authenticate(String strUserName, String strPassword)
at QBWebConnector.localhost.WCWebService.authenticate(String strUserName, String strPassword)
at QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.authenticate(String UserName, String Password)
at QBWebConnector.WebService.do_authenticate(String& ticket, String& companyFileName)
Source = System.Web.Services
```

And the PHP code is as below. My DSN is right. PHP version is 5.5+:

```
 <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
if (function_exists('date_default_timezone_set')){
    date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
}

require_once '../../QuickBooks.php';
$user = 'quickbooks';
$pass = 'password';

$map = array(
    QUICKBOOKS_ADD_CUSTOMER => array( '_quickbooks_customer_add_request', '_quickbooks_customer_add_response' ),
);
$errmap = array(
    3070 => '_quickbooks_error_stringtoolong'
);

$hooks = array();
$log_level = QUICKBOOKS_LOG_DEBUG;              
$soapserver = QUICKBOOKS_SOAPSERVER_BUILTIN;

$soap_options = array();

$handler_options = array(
    'deny_concurrent_logins' => false, 
    'deny_reallyfast_logins' => false, 
);

$driver_options = array();

$callback_options = array();
$dsn = 'mysql://root@localhost/quickbooks_server';

if (!QuickBooks_Utilities::initialized($dsn)){
    QuickBooks_Utilities::initialize($dsn);
    QuickBooks_Utilities::createUser($dsn, $user, $pass);
    $primary_key_of_your_customer = 5;

    $Queue = new QuickBooks_WebConnector_Queue($dsn);
    $Queue->enqueue(QUICKBOOKS_ADD_CUSTOMER, $primary_key_of_your_customer);
}

$Server = new QuickBooks_WebConnector_Server($dsn, $map, $errmap, $hooks, $log_level, $soapserver, QUICKBOOKS_WSDL, $soap_options, $handler_options, $driver_options, $callback_options);
$response = $Server->handle(true, true);

  function _quickbooks_customer_add_request($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $version, $locale)
{
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <?qbxml version="2.0"?>
    <QBXML>
        <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
            <CustomerAddRq requestID="' . $requestID . '">
                <CustomerAdd>
                    <Name>ConsoliBYTE, LLC (' . mt_rand() . ')</Name>
                    <CompanyName>ConsoliBYTE, LLC</CompanyName>
                    <FirstName>Keith</FirstName>
                    <LastName>Palmer</LastName>
                    <BillAddress>
                        <Addr1>ConsoliBYTE, LLC</Addr1>
                        <Addr2>134 Stonemill Road</Addr2>
                        <City>Mansfield</City>
                        <State>CT</State>
                        <PostalCode>06268</PostalCode>
                        <Country>United States</Country>
                    </BillAddress>
                    <Phone>860-634-1602</Phone>
                    <AltPhone>860-429-0021</AltPhone>
                    <Fax>860-429-5183</Fax>
                    <Email>Keith@ConsoliBYTE.com</Email>
                    <Contact>Keith Palmer</Contact>
                </CustomerAdd>
            </CustomerAddRq>
        </QBXMLMsgsRq>
    </QBXML>';

return $xml;
  }


  function _quickbooks_customer_add_response($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $xml, $idents)
 {  
   //
 }

  function _quickbooks_error_stringtoolong($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $xml, $errnum, $errmsg)
  {
mail('your-email@your-domain.com', 
    'QuickBooks error occured!', 
    'QuickBooks thinks that ' . $action . ': ' . $ID . ' has a value which will not fit in a QuickBooks field...');
   }
```

Comment: The info you posted is no where near enough information to even being to help you troubleshoot. Post your code. Post what you've tried so far -- Have you run the Web Connector? What does it say? What does the Web Connector log file say? Is this your entire quickbooks_log SQL table? What does the rest of it look like? What customer are you expecting to get added? Why are you expecting a customer to get added?

Comment: I've put the SQLlog and QWClog for you to look into. Response is not well-formed XML may be the main problem. I've searched and looked the answer in consolibyte forum but could not solve it.

Comment: the SQL user table's status field contains 'e' and the company file is not added into SQL user table too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error:

> Response is not well-formed XML

Means you have a PHP or SQL error. It seems you found the error here:

> [02-Nov-2015 14:55:28 America/New_York] PHP Deprecated:  mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in C:\xampp\htdocs\qb\QuickBooks\Driver\Sql\Mysql.php on line 289

You need to fix that error.

You can do that by changing your `$dsn` string to use a non-deprecated db driver, for example:

`$dsn = 'mysqli://...';`

Comment: probably the answer is not right. I assume its a SOAP Exception. As the codebase is large enough, its taking time to track from where and why its being generated. As an author, you know it far better than me.

Comment: The source of error seems to be System.Web.Services. Probably this has not been for $dsn. The $dsn was able to create tables inside MySQL database. So what is the logic the error namely Response is not well-formed for $dsn?

Comment: The code you've posted will NOT generate SOAP exceptions. Your code, as you posted it, WILL cause the "Response is not well-formed XML" error to show up in the Web Connector because PHP is outputting error message about the deprecated mysql extension prior to outputting the SOAP envelope. Thus, the Web Connector doesn't think the SOAP XML is well-formed because it's been corrupted by the PHP error output.

Comment: The source of the error is NOT System.Web.Services. That is the code that's reporting the error on the Web Connector side, but that is NOT the source of the error. Follow the steps I outlined above before doing anything else. If you still have problems, post an updated log file and your updated code.

Comment: The problem is solved after the $dsn is changed. Keith Palmer is an wonderful author.

Comment: One supplementary question- why is it important to authenticate for the QuickBooks? Does it change rows any table in MySQL or anyway linked with User/Role in the QuickBooks?

Comment: QuickBooks requires you to authenticate as your QuickBooks user so that it knows that you're allowed to add/update data in QuickBooks. The Web Connector authenticates to the web service so that the Web Connector knows it's allowed to see the data the web service is trying to send to QuickBooks.